# Update column Dataframe column based on list values

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe columns `id` and `articles` and 3 lists `a_list` , `b_list`, `c_list` as below.

```
a_list=[4, 10], b_list=[11,3], c_list=[3,6]

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 4), (2, 3), (5, 6)], ("id", "articles"))
```

I want to update column `Found` based on the match between value of dataframe column `articles` to lists `(a_list, b_list,c_list)`

Currently , I am able to do only if 2 list are there, with below code .

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func                    
df.withColumn('E', func.when(df.articles.isin(a_list), 'Found in a_list').otherwise('Found in b_list'))
```

How to extrapolate for more than 2 lists ?

Expected output

```
+---+--------+---------------+                                                  
| id|articles|          Found|
+---+--------+---------------+
|  1|       4|Found in a_list|
|  2|       3|Found in b_list|
|  5|       6|Found in c_list|
+---+--------+---------------+
```